# how to Update QT 4.5.3 of OpenSuse 11.2 to QT 4.7.3?

Tags: compiling, opensuse, software-installation

I just installed QT 4.7.3 in OpenSuse 11.2 (which has 4.5.3). I ran `configure`, `gmake`, and `gmake install`, but when I check qmake's version, it's still returning 4.5.3.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Guess: the new version was installed in `/usr/local` (in particular, it installed `/usr/local/bin/qmake`), since you didn't specify a location. (`/usr/local` is probably the right place.) The distribution-provided qmake is in `/usr/bin/qmake`. Your running shell has cached the information that `qmake` is `/usr/bin/qmake`. Run `hash qmake` to make it refresh its cache. A new shell instance will find `/usr/local/bin/qmake`, as long as `/usr/local/bin` is ahead of `/usr/bin` in the `$PATH` (which it should be).

Comment: 4.7.3's qmake gets installed at /usr/loca/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.3/bin ... I tried running "hash qmake" but still returns the old version. How do I point it to the new qt version?